# two-sample proportions hypothesis test: 10 successes and failures rule

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I am learning the hypothesis test with two sample proportions. Suppose the sample sizes and number of successes are ($n_1, y_1$) and  ($n_2, y_2$), for the two samples, respectively.
Let the true proportions of successes be $p_1, p_2$.

Null hypothesis $H_0$: $p_1-p_2 = 0$

Alternative hypothesis $H_a$: $p_1 - p_2 \ne 0$

Everywhere I have seen, it is required that both samples need to have at least $10$ successes and failures. I understand that a binomial to be approximated by a normal distribution needs to have that condition met for a single distribution.

Here, the null hypothesis is that  $p_1 = p_2$. Then the estimate for the true proportion $p$  under that is $\hat p = \frac{y_1 + y_2}{n_1 + n_2}$. Is it not enough that the number of combined successes and failures meet $y_1 + y_2 > 10 $ and $n_1 + n_2 - y_1 - y_2 > 10$? Under the null hypothesis, then, would that imply that  the individual samples are drawn from approximately normal distributions if $\hat p n_1, (1 - \hat p) n_1, \hat p n_2, (1 - \hat p) n_2 > 10$? This would then further imply that $\hat p_1 - \hat p_2$ is approximately normally distributed.

Comment: An example of the conditions in my question is follows. Suppose $n_1 = n_2 = 50$, $y_1=7, y_2 = 13$. Then $\hat p = (7+13)/100 = 0.2$. So $\hat p n_1 = \hat p n_2 = 10$, and $(1 - \hat p) n_1 =   (1 - \hat p) n_2 = 40$. Can we say that these samples are from approximately normal distributions under the null hypothesis $H_0$?

Answer (score 1):

The "10 successes and failures" rule of thumb only informs whether you could reasonably use a normal approximation for the test statistic, or whether an exact test statistic should be used.

That said, you can immediately see how your proposed modification to the rule to consider the overall number of successes and failures across the two groups is inadequate by constructing an extreme example such as:

$$(y_1, n_1) = (1, 2), \quad (y_2, n_2) = (9000, 10000).$$

This easily meets your criterion but the sample size in the first group is tiny, meaning there is very little information that we can infer about the parameter $p_1$.

Let's actually look at testing the hypothesis $$H_0 : p_1 = p_2 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : p_1 \ne p_2. \tag{1}$$  I argue that this is nearly equivalent to the test $$H_0 : p_1 = 0.9 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : p_1 \ne 0.9. \tag{2}$$  This is because the observed proportion in group 2 is based on an extremely large sample size; thus the information contained in the data about the true value of $p_2$ is very high.  For instance, the standard error of $\hat p_2 = 0.9$ is $$SE(\hat p_2) = \sqrt{\frac{0.9(1-0.9)}{10000}} = 0.003.$$  Therefore, the $p$-value of the test for hypothesis $(1)$ will be very close to the $p$-value for hypothesis $(2)$.

With this in mind, it is easy to compute the exact probability of a Type I error for hypothesis $(2)$:

$$\begin{align}
p &= \Pr[Y_1 \le 1 \mid p_1 = 0.9] \\ 
&= 1 - \Pr[Y_1 = 2 \mid p_1 = 0.9] \\
&= 1 - (0.9)^2 \\
&= 0.19.
\end{align}$$

This is certainly inadequate evidence to reject $H_0$.  In other words, if we have a coin where the chance of seeing heads on any given flip is $90\%$, the chance that we see $0$ or $1$ head in $2$ flips is $19\%$.

What this tells us is that both groups must have sufficient data, not just to use a normal approximation, but to even have the possibility of rejecting the null hypothesis when an exact test statistic is used.  This is why your proposed rule of thumb is flawed.

Comment: The example is informative, thanks. However, it does not meet the entire set of "rule of thumb": $\hat p n_1, (1 - \hat p) n_1, \hat p n_2, (1 - \hat p) n_2 > 10$, where all of these are also greater than 10. Perhaps you could give an example that also satisfies these, yet does not work?

Comment: @creet You asked:  "Is it not enough that the number of combined successes and failures meet $y_1 + y_2 > 10$ and $n_1 + n_2 - y_1 - y_2 > 10$?"  Then you assert that under $H_0$, such a condition would imply the inequalities you mentioned in your reply.  None of this is true.  I showed you an example where the first part is wrong; and under the null, the second part does not follow from the first.

Comment: @creet Clearly, if we come up with a case (such as the one I provided) that satisfies the "combined" condition but does not meet your second set of criteria, then that means your total criteria are **more complicated** than the original set of criteria that only needs $y_1, y_2, n_1 - y_1, n_2 - y_2 > 10$.

Comment: Perhaps I should have stated it slightly differently. Sorry about the confusion. I wasn't asserting the second part follows from the first. Second part is in addition to the first. There is an "if" in the second statement.

Comment: I don't see why it's more complicated than $y_1, y_2, n_1-y_1, n_2-y_2 > 10$. It's simply whether the conditions as in the question are okay. They are different and allow more room in cases where the original conditions may not be met.